Pass dictionary to OrchestrationTrigger and ActivityTrigger in Durable Functions
I have a durable function with orchestrators and activities. That works fine with basic types or classes. But now I have a Dictionary<string, object>. The activities can't be bind and the orchestrations can't be found. How can I achieve that?
Use case:
There is a JSON input and one part of that changes by process type. So one field contains a dynamic structure. So I have all around in a class model and this one field as Dictionary<string, object> because there can also be sub structures.


I have a Dictionary<string, object>. The activities can't be bind and the orchestrations can't be found. How can I achieve that?

You can use below code to do the same:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace TestRithwik
{
    public static class RithFunc
    {
        [Function(nameof(RithFunc))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ricxt)
        {
            ILogger ri_logger = ricxt.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(RithFunc));
            var ri_in_Json = ricxt.GetInput<string>();
            var ri_inp_Dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(ri_in_Json);
            var riout = new List<string>();
            foreach (var rith in ri_inp_Dict)
            {
                riout.Add(await ricxt.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(RithAct), JsonSerializer.Serialize(rith)));
            }
            return riout;
        }

        [Function(nameof(RithAct))]
        public static string RithAct([ActivityTrigger] string rijson)
        {
            var rith = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(rijson);
            return $"Hello Rithwik Bojja, item with key {rith.Key} and value {rith.Value} is processed";
        }

        [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient ricl)
        {
            var testdic = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "name", "Rithwik" },
                { "Test", new { Val = "Bojja" } },
                { "id", 8 }
            };
            var valjson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(testdic);
            string rid = await ricl.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(RithFunc), valjson);
            return await ricl.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, rid);
        }
    }
}

Output:

